# macOS randomly trying to verify rust binaries and hanging

Tags: macos, rust, rust-cargo

macOS Monterey on an M1 MacBook Air has recently started randomly “verifying” my own Rust binaries when I run them with `cargo run`. This is, of course, completely unnecessary, and moreover, it hangs, leaving a stray window that cannot be closed. The only way I've figured out how to close the window is to reboot the system.

Any idea how to a) disable the verification and b) close the hung window?

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` does nothing because the binaries are not “apps” with relevant attributes.

[image: stuck verifying]

Comment: Do you know what triggers this verification? Do you know what this verifying entails?

Comment: Same issue. I usually face this when trying to do unit testing or cargo build

Comment: What version of Monterey?

Comment: I have Monterey 12.3.1. I am not sure what exactly causes the verification, but it starts randomly sometimes after `cargo run`, possibly also already after `cargo build`. Most the time there is no problem.

Comment: That's something that's relating to mounting a disk image. Not sure how Rust is triggering that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the window listing Python script from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317531/how-to-determine-which-one-process-owns-particular-window, I figured out that the culprit is `CoreServicesUIAgent`. Killing it will close the window.